# Bash: failed to print output to csv

Tags: bash

I have the following code which reads in a csv file and then try to match some column by regex and then afterwards output a few rows and then print the rows into a csv. **Problem** is that the final csv contains the output in several rows but they are in the same column.

```
#!/bin/bash
files=( XW[1-2]something[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].csv)
for i in ${files[@]}; do
    awk -F "," '{if($2=="303" && match($4,/^AB[0-9]/) && $5=="3"){print $4,$3,$9;}}' < $i > "201_testing.csv"
done
```

Then the output is all stored in 1 single column.

```
AB1 659362 20180628
AB1 1445794 20180927
AB1 2822050 20191230
AB1 6360994 20201230
AB1 7999394 20180427
AB1 10948514 20180328
AB1 76484514 20181228
AB1 149622690 20211230
AB1 149688226 20221229
```

How can I make the output displayed in multiple columns (in this case 3 columns) instead of just 1 single column ?

Comment: You did not set the **output** field separator in awk: `awk -F, -v OFS=, ...`

Comment: In your code, you have `awk -F ","` -- you need to change change to be `awk -F "," -v OFS=","` -- `-F` sets the **input** field separator, but to output with commas, you need to also set the **output** field separator.

Comment: More information at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I got it now.

Comment: Acutally, I want to ask  how can I set multiple variables ? i.e. `awk -v OFS="," pattern="$var1" ` such that I can use "pattern" for matching regex later on in the if statement?

Comment: Use `-v` multiple times to create awk variables: `awk -v OFS="," -v pattern="$var1"`